# Meaning of React LinkProps

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router

I think LinkProps is a type of props, but I don't know what it means to specify Omit<RouterLinkProps, 'to'>. Please tell me.

```
import { Link as RouterLink, LinkProps as RouterLinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { LinkProps } from '@mui/material/Link';

const LinkBehavior = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLAnchorElement,
  Omit<RouterLinkProps, 'to'> & { href: RouterLinkProps['to'] }
>((props, ref) => {
  const { href, ...other } = props;
  // Map href (MUI) -> to (react-router)
  return <RouterLink ref={ref} to={href} {...other} />;
});
```

Reference site:.https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/routing/

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Omit<RouterLinkProps, 'to'>` is simply removing the `to` prop from the `react-router-dom` `Link` component's props type definition. See [Omitting Keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) for further details.

[LinkProps](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/f3d87dcc91fbd6fd646064b88b4be52c15114603/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L257-L263)

```
export interface LinkProps
  extends Omit<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, "href"> {
  reloadDocument?: boolean;
  replace?: boolean;
  state?: any;
  to: To; // <-- removes this prop
}
```

The rest of the type is effectively moving the `to` prop to an `href` prop.

```
Omit<RouterLinkProps, 'to'> & { href: RouterLinkProps['to'] }
```

Which should result in a type as follows:

```
export interface LinkProps
  extends Omit<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, "href"> {
  reloadDocument?: boolean;
  replace?: boolean;
  state?: any;
  href: To;
}
```